# Extracting several models from a Backbone Collection that matches List of Model IDs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I have a Backbone collection of Facilities. The model associated with the collection is a Facility with FacilityCode as the model Id attribute.

Now I have a list of FacilityCode in an array. Is there any simple way of creating a collection with all the models which has matching FacilityCode in this array?

I can use collection.get(id) function to get the models one by one. But I am looking for a function to which I can pass an array of IDs which will return a collection of matching models.

Answer (score 3):

[filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) is useful for this sort of thing. If you would like, you can wrap it nicely in the definition of your collection object:

```
Facilities = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // ...

    getAllForCodes: function(facilityCodes) {
        var models = this.filter(function(facility) {
            return (_.indexOf(facilityCodes, facility.get('FacilityCode')) !== -1);
        }); 
        return new Facilities(models);
    }

});
```

...and the use it to get all facilities for an array of facility codes:

```
var myFacilities = facilities.getAllForCodes([1, 2, 3]);
```